# how to Add Shared Project to WPF Project in VS2019

Tags: c#, wpf, shared-project

I've created an WPF Project.
Since the project has become big enough for me to maintain I wish to break its code into several Shared Projects.

So can I add/create Shared Project for C# & WPF?

I'm asking this since I cannot find any template in New Projects for creating Shared Project for C# & WPF

Thanks in Advance
Amit Saraf

Comment: What about creating class libraries, saraf ji?

Comment: by adding class libraries, I would need to add all the references again n again & also if i want to use the same in another project it would be same process again

Comment: You can create project template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new class library (File->New->Project in Visual Studio) using the `WPF Custom Control Library (.NET Framework)` or ``WPF Custom Control Library` template depending on your target framework
- Move the code (copy and paste) to this new project from the existing application project
- Add a project reference to the new project from the existing application project (Project->Add Reference->Projects->Solution in Visual Studio